# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] error while working with angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to create a simple regisration form which will in the end tell me whether I have registered or not . But I am stuck with this error . 
This is my app.js file

```
    (function (){
    'use strict';
     angular.module('modulemain',[]).controller('ModuleController',ModuleController);

     ModuleController.$inject=['$scope'];

    function ModuleController($scope){
    $scope.fname='';
    $scope.lname='';
    $scope.mname='';
    $scope.email='';
    $scope.password='';
    $scope.confirm='';
    $scope.msg='';
    $scope.msg1='';

    $scope.submission=function(){
      if($scope.password!=$scope.confirm){
        $scope.msg="Password did not matched";
        $scope.msg1="Try Entering Password";
      }
      else{
        $scope.msg="Registration Successful";
        $scope.msg1="Welcome $scope.fname";
      }

    };

  };

});
```

And this is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" ng-app='app'>
<head>
   <title>Registration</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src='app.js'></script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="form" ng-controller="ModuleController">
  First Name: <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="Enter First name" ng-model="fname"><br>
  Middle Name: <input type="text" id="mname" placeholder="Enter middle name" ng-model="mname"><br>
  Last Name :<input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Enter last name" ng-model="lname"><br>
  Email: <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email address" ng-model="email"><br>
  Password: <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Enter password" ng-model="password"><br>
  Confirm Password: <input type="password" id="c_pass" placeholder="Re-enter the password" ng- 
  model="confirm"><br>

  <button type="submit" ng-click="submit()"> Submit</button>
  <br><br>
  <div>
    {{msg}}<br>
    {{msg1}}
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

And I am getting following error

```
angular.min.js:7 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angula

at angular.min.js:7
at angular.min.js:43
at r (angular.min.js:8)
at g (angular.min.js:42)
at fb (angular.min.js:46)
at c (angular.min.js:22)
at Uc (angular.min.js:22)
at Ae (angular.min.js:21)
at angular.min.js:348
at HTMLDocument.b (angular.min.js:38)
```

Can anyone help me with this ?? I am new to Angular Js .

Comment: if possible please create plunker so that we can resolve and update there

Comment: self invoking function need to get called it self `(function(){})()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('modulemain',[]).controller('ModuleController',ModuleController);

    ModuleController.$inject=['$scope'];

    function ModuleController($scope){
        $scope.fname='';
        $scope.lname='';
        $scope.mname='';
        $scope.email='';
        $scope.password='';
        $scope.confirm='';
        $scope.msg='';
        $scope.msg1='';

        $scope.submission=function(){
            if($scope.password!=$scope.confirm){
                $scope.msg="Password did not matched";
                $scope.msg1="Try Entering Password";
            } else {
                $scope.msg="Registration Successful";
                $scope.msg1="Welcome $scope.fname";
            }
        };
    };
})(angular);
```